# How to call stored variables in reducer from action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have the variables user_id and token that are generated in authActions.js but I need to reuse them in couple more functions from different js files.

How can I store this in a session after has been generated and remove them when log out?

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(SIGNIN_URL, { email, password }).then((response) => {
      var { user_id, token } = response.data;
      dispatch(authUser(user_id, token)); // here I dispatch the values to authUser const in the same file
      onSignIn(user_id);
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(addAlert("Could not log in."));
    });
  };
}

export const authUser = (user_id, token) => {
  return {
    type: 'AUTH_USER',
    user_id,
    token
  }
}
```

my authReducer.js

```
var defaultState = {
  user_id: undefined,
  token: undefined
}

module.exports = (state=defaultState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'AUTH_USER':
      return {
        user_id: action.user_id,
        token: action.token
      }

    case 'UNAUTH_USER':
      return {
        user_id: undefined,
        token: undefined
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and here is my jobsAction.js where I would like to use them

```
export function createJob(title, company, avatar, description ) {
  return function (dispatch) {
      return axios.post(JOBS_URL(user_id), { title, company, avatar, description }, {
        headers: { authorization: token }
      }).then((response) => {
        dispatch(addJob(response.data.job));
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch(addAlert("Couldn't create job."));
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: You can use the `localStorage` , from this you can achieve what you want.

Comment: use redux and create a reducer called `user` with all necessary states

Answer (score 1):

You are getting it in an action creator, so dispatch an action with `userId`, store it in the redux state. Then you`ll be able to get it from that state and use wherever you want.

Comment: @MarkusHayner so, further steps depends on where you wanna call the `createJob`. You can get `user_id` from a closure of a component, that connected to a store. Or, you can subscribe to the store by `store.subscribe(listener)` to know about changes and call `store.getState()` for getting renewed state inside `listener`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use localStorage. for persist item you can use `localStorage.set(key,value)`.
 you can retrieve value like that `localStorage.get(key)` and `localStorage.remove(key)` for delete.

you can read documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage